# 'String' is not identical to 'Int8' - SWIFT

Tags: xcode, swift, uipickerview

I am learning the language and I am trying to make a stop watch and countdown timer app. 
I have done everything for the stopwatch but the countdown timer is giving me troubles.

I have a Picker View to set the label to what it should count down from. That is where I am having troubles. I can't seem to figure out how to get the NSTimer to countdown from what the user picked from the Picker View.

```
//UIPickerView

var numbers = ["1.00", "2.00", "3.00", "4.00", "5.00", "6.00", "7.00","8.00", "9.00", "10.00", "11.00","12.00","13.00", "14.00", "15.00", "16.00", "17.00", "18.00", "19.00", "20.00"]


func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return numbers.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return numbers[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){

    var displayTime = "\(numbers[row])"
    timerDisplay.text = String(displayTime--) **LINE THAT GIVES ERROR**
    timeInMilliseconds -= 0.01        
}
```

This is what I have for the picker view. Let me know if you need to see any more code to help me out. 
Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: I have edited the original. I added which line gives the error.

Comment: `displayTime` is already a string, so "--" on it doesn't make much sense.  (Also, `"\(numbers[row])"` is pretty much the same as `numbers[row]` ...  both strings.)

Comment: @PhillipMills So what should I do? How do I make the NSTimer countdown from what number is chosen in the pickerView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the ".00" part in the text, then you need to extract the whole number to do the arithmetic.

Something like:

```
var text = ""
var whole: Int? = nil
if let index = numbers[row].rangeOfString(".") {
    whole = numbers[row].substringToIndex(index.startIndex).toInt()
}
if whole != nil {
    text = "\(whole! - 1).00"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do I put that block of code into the didSelectRow function?  @PhillipMills